# Can we rewrite multiple blocks of same core extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, overrides, override-block

Can we rewrite multiple blocks of a core extension like `catalog` ? like this :

```
<blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <class_name_here>YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Your_New_Class_Here</class_name_here>
            <2nd_class_name_here>YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Your_2nd_Class_Here</2nd_class_name_here>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Do you want to rewrite of same class?

Comment: not the same class two different one, the answer bellow is exactly what i needed to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, assuming that you want to rewrite :

- `Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` and
- `Catalog/Block/Product.php`

In your `config.xml` module :

```
<config>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Module_Name_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                <product>Module_Name_Block_Product</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</config>
```

Comment: it worked :D i read on stackoverflow some said it's not possible.

Comment: Yes it works ;)